# Excel VBA - Tricky Indexing Logic to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have run into an issue with some logic in VBA which I have found in my experience very tricky to figure out, I will attempt to explain it below.

I have 4 columns in my worksheet, structured as follows

```
|    A     |  |    B    |  |  C |  |  D | 
|First Name|  |Last Name|  |Type|  |Text|
```

I am in search of some VBA which can effectively scan the **First Name** column, once it encounters a blank, it initiates the following logic

> 1. Look in the Type (C) Column
> 2. If it encounters text in the type column that says **Journal** then check the cell located in the same row in the **Text (D)** column
> 3. Take the free text in the **text** column, put it into an array.
> 4. Use the text in the array and scan the **First Name** column for matching text entries, if it finds a match then take the matching text in the **Text** column and paste it into the **First Name** column.  Do this until the array runs out.
> 5. Restart step 4 for the **Last Name** column
> 6. Loop back to step 1
>
> NOTES:  The text in the **Text** column is a free text extract from a third party application (SAP), therefore I am running off the assumption that if it contains a First Name or Last Name, it can match it with the entries already located in the **First Name** and **Last Name** column

I have been looking everywhere for syntax which can do this efficiently but I am stuck with writing the logic for this and need some advice from the community, any ideas?

UPDATE:
An example of the data would be like this

```
|     A       |   |      B      |   |     C      |   |     D           |
| First Name  |   |  Last Name  |   |   Type     |   |   Text          |
| Michael     |   |  Jackson    |   |    WE      |   |  SAP CATS       |

|             |   |             |   |    SS      |   |  CATS O/H Michael Jackson|
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the text in Column D?

Comment: I might be missing something, but it seems like the above logic will accomplish absolutely nothing. If you paste over data with exactly what was already there, what are you accomplishing?

Comment: It would help if I gave some context, the data above is actually a mirror of an extract of timesheeting and accrual data from SAP.  If the person does a timesheet (michael jackson), the persons name comes up in the first name / last name column.  However if its an accrual for michael jacksons time, it doesn't come up as a timesheet entry, rather it comes up in Column D as a free text entry.  Its a disconnect in the way SAP records data as accruals are not considered timesheet entries.  I need to normalize it in order to achieve an automated extract to a financial tool which I am producing.

Comment: Ahh, so on that second line, you're wanting the code to actually put the Michael into Column A, and the Jackson into column B? (But only if the type is Journal)

Comment: Thats it!  It needs to ignore the CATS O/H or any other pointless text aside from teh first name / last name.  It needs to happen with RA (reverse accrual), AC (Accrual) and SS (Journals)

Comment: Alright I'll see what I can do. This one looks fun

Comment: Is the ONLY text that would be in column D "Michael Jackson"? If so, you could do this with a function and avoid any VBA at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure why you want to do it, but here is vba that implements the logic you have described:

```
Sub t()
    For i = 2 To Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row
        '1. Look in the Type (C) Column
        typ = Range("C" & i).Value

        '2. If it encounters text in the type column that says Journal then...
        If typ = "Journal" Then

            '...check the cell located in the same row in the Text (D) column
            txt = Range("D" & i).Value

            '3. Take the free text in the text column, put it into an array.
            txtArray = Split(txt, " ")

            '4. Use the text in the array and scan the First Name column for matching
            'text entries, if it finds a match then take the matching text in the
            'Text column and paste it into the First Name column. Do this until the
            'array runs out.

            For Each t In txtArray
                For j = 2 To Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row
                    If Range("A" & j).Value = t Then
                        match_txt = Range("D" & j).Value
                        Range("A" & i).Value = match_txt
                    End If
                Next j
            Next t

            '5. Restart step 4 for the Last Name column
            'note: i would just do this in the above loop.
            'split out here so that you can see step 5 seperately from step 4
            For Each t In txtArray
                For j = 2 To Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row
                    If Range("B" & j).Value = t Then
                        match_txt = Range("D" & j).Value
                        Range("B" & i).Value = match_txt
                    End If
                Next j
            Next t

        End If

    '6. loop back to step 1
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: this is really close. All you need to do to fix this is change the line of code that says "match_txt = Range("D" & j).Value" to "match_txt = t" (it's on there twice).

Comment: Also, the first line of code -- For i = 2 To Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row -- uses column A to determine the last used column, which is probably not reliable. Might be better to use column C, or otherwise just make sure to type something at the very bottom of column A to make sure every row is processed

Comment: This is very very close, it certainly does well, right up until this line here

    match_txt = Range("D" & j).Value

It seems to be not copying the name, rather it copies a piece of text that might be 10 rows down from the target, its confusing as to why.  Trying to work that out on my end.

Comment: @PootyToot, did you get it to work with what I said? It worked for me when I replaced that one line

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I really understand the Text column and I'm not really around a computer with real Excel (Mac Excel sucks) but off the top of my head I'd approach it something like this.

```
Dim wSheet1 as Worksheet

Sub main()
    Dim i As Long

    Set wSheet1 = Sheets(wSheet1)

    For i = 2 To getLastUsedRow(wSheet1)

        # Requirements #1 and #2
        If wSheet1.Cells(i, "A") = "" And wSheet1.Cells(i, "C") = "Journal" Then
            processText(i, wSheet1.Range("A:A"))
        End If

        # Requirement #5
        If wSheet1.Cells(i, "B") = "" And wSheet1.Cells(i, "C") = "Journal" Then
            processText(i, wSheet1.Range("B:B"))
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub processText(i as Long, searchCol As Range)
    Dim words as Variant
    text = wSheet1.Cells(i, "D")

    # Requirement #3
    words = Split(text, " ")

    For j = 0 To UBound(words)
        word = words(i)
        vTest = Application.VLookup(word, searchCol, 1, False)
        If IsError(vTest) = False Then
            # Requirement #4
            wSheet1.Cells(i, "A") = word
        End If
    Next j
End Sub

Function getLastUsedRow(w as Worksheet)
    getLastUsedRow = w.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Function
```